# Can you explain implicit graphs(in graph theory) with a simple example?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I can see a wiki article here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph
But would love to understand this with simpler intuitive examples.

Answer (score 4):

The [Collatz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem) is a nice example of an implicit graph. The Collatz function c(n) is defined as n/2 if n is even, or 3n + 1 if n is odd. So for example c(32) = 32/2 = 16 because 32 is even, while c(5) = 3*5 + 1 = 16 because 5 is odd.

The problem is, if you choose a number n to start with, and keep applying c, does it eventually reach 1? For example, starting at 5, c(5) = 16, then c(16) = 8, then c(8) = 4, then c(4) = 2, then c(2) = 1.

It may be helpful to visualise what the function c does [by drawing a graph](https://martin-thoma.com/the-collatz-sequence/), where there is an edge from each number n to c(n):

[image]

Thinking about it as a graph, the Collatz conjecture states that every node has a path to the node 1. But to investigate this problem, there is no need to store the graph in memory; we can just use the function c(n) to calculate where the edge from n goes to. Conversely, if we want to know the edges in the other direction, then n always has an edge from 2n, and it has an edge from (n - 1)/3 when n - 1 is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

The page you mentioned provides the Rubik's Cube example.

Another (similar) example is chess. Vertices in the graph are legal chess positions and edges are moves that take the game from one position to another. Algorithms like [Minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) or [Alpha-beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) work with this implicit graph without storing it in memory (which would be impossible due to its enormous size)

A game of chess is a path in this implicit graph. Repetitions are cycles. Stalemate and checkmate positions are [sinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree) (there are no outgoing edges). Transpositions are different paths between the same pair of vertices (e.g. after **1.** d4 Nf6 **2.** c4 and **1.** c4 Nf6 **2.** d4).

[Endgame tablebases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_tablebase) are one instance in which chess algorithms operate on the explicit representation of the graph (or rather, a nontrivial portion of it). To generate a database of results for all possible positions for a combination of pieces (such as KQP versus KQ, or king, queen and pawn versus king and queen), computers consider all the moves between all these positions, as well as captures and promotions. Everything that can proved to be a win is discovered in this way, and everything that is not discovered in this way is a theoretical draw.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is the **implicit graph for the well-known [Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) puzzle**:

- Disks of various diameters are stacked on a number of rods.
- A start configuration is given. Here, on each
  rod, the stacked disks are ordered in decreasing size, the smallest
  on top. (A typical start configuration consists of three rods, and
  all disks are stacked on the first rod.)
- A goal configuration is specified. (A typical goal configuration
  demands, that at the end, all disks have to be on the second rod.)
- In each step of solving the puzzle, only one disk may be moved.
  It needs to be taken from the top position of a rod. It needs to
  be placed either on an empty rod or on
  the top disk of another rod, and this top disk must not be smaller.

**All such problems**, with different numbers of rods, numbers of disks, and sizes of disks, **can be described by a single (!) implicit graph**, together **with the specific start and goal configuration**.

In order to illustrate this by concrete code, we choose to describe a configuration of the puzzle by a tuple of rod configurations, and each rod configuration by a tuple of the sizes of the disks stacked on the rod. We define a **function that takes a puzzle configuration (a vertex of our graph) as parameter** and **reports the possible following puzzle configurations (positive adjacent vertices, describing the edges of our graph)**, here in Python syntax:

```
def next_vertices(rods, _):
    """ Adjacency function specifying the implicit graph for Towers of Hanoi """
    # For each non-empty rod (we might take a disk from here)
    for from_no in range(len(rods)):
        if not rods[from_no]:
            continue
        # For each other rod (we might place a disk here)
        for to_no in range(len(rods)):
            if from_no == to_no:
                continue
            # Destination rod needs to be empty, or its top disk large enough
            if not rods[to_no] or rods[from_no][0] <= rods[to_no][0]:
                # Move top disk from rod from_no to rod to_no 
                tmp_rods = list(rods)
                tmp_rods[to_no] = (rods[from_no][0], *rods[to_no])
                tmp_rods[from_no] = rods[from_no][1:]
                # Report this as an allowed move to a positive adjacent vertex
                yield tuple(tmp_rods)
```

(Please ignore the unused second parameter of the function - we need to specify it to make the following code work.)

When we like to solve the puzzle using the lowest possible number of moves, this means to **find the shortest (edge count) path from a given start configuration to a given goal configuration**. This can be done by using the [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Libraries that can handle implicit graphs, e.g., [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) for C++ or [NoGraphs](https://pypi.org/project/nographs/) for Python, typically provide a Breadth-first search.

This is shown in the following interactice Python session, that uses NoGraphs ("pip install NoGraphs"):

```
>>> import nographs as nog
>>> traversal = nog.TraversalBreadthFirst(next_vertices)
>>> start, goal = ((1,2,3), (), ()), ((), (1,2,3), ())
>>> vertex = traversal.start_from(start, build_paths=True).go_to(goal)

>>> print(f"Goal {vertex} reachable with a minimum of {traversal.depth} steps.")
Goal ((), (1, 2, 3), ()) reachable with a minimum of 7 steps.

>>> print("Path example:")
...     for vertex in traversal.paths[vertex]:
...         print(vertex)
Path example:
((1, 2, 3), (), ())
((2, 3), (1,), ())
((3,), (1,), (2,))
((3,), (), (1, 2))
((), (3,), (1, 2))
((1,), (3,), (2,))
((1,), (2, 3), ())
((), (1, 2, 3), ())
```

Note, that the graph (function next_vertices) describes the rules for **infinitely many vertices** (puzzle configurations) **and edges** (possible moves between configurations). And this needs **(nearly) zero runtime and memory**, and **no library with a graph container**.

The search automatically traverses only the vertices that are to be visited to solve the specific problem with the chosen search strategy for the specific start and goal configuration.

In the [documentation of NoGraphs](https://nographs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concept_and_examples.html#examples), you can find many other examples.

Comment: Please avoid attaching external links on SO as it is uncertain if those will become dead. whereas, you can also explain those examples here and then in the end provide links for better clarity just to be on the safer side.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @surajs1n: Thanks for the comment. I replaced the answer by a full example, and moved the link to further examples to the end.